# Поднятие прокси ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, прокси

Нашел хороший мануал по поднятию прокси на линукс сервере, единственная проблема в том, что у автора, похоже, был другой дистрибутив, в мануале была написано следующее:

> Берём прокси-адреса, которые доступны нам на сервере. Берём самый
>   первый, основной адрес, и выполняем с ним следующие действия. Сначала
>   вводим команду (`nano /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:1`) и
>   вписываем туда:
>
> ```
> DEVICE=eth0:1 BOOTPROTO=static ONBOOT=yes IPADDR=ваш IP
> NETMASK=255.255.255.255
> ```

У меня находит только такие папки в `etc`:

```
root@194-58-122-28:/etc# cd sys
sysctl.d/ systemd/
```

Куда мне прописать данные строки?
У меня ubuntu 12.04

Comment: ps: спасибо за редактирование

Comment: 12.04 скоро перестанет поддерживаться. Если система ставится с нуля - лучше всё-таки ставить 14.04 или подождать 16.04, которая выйдет в конце апреля.

Comment: Это все конечно хорошо, но думаю не существенно будет ли поддерживаться 12.04 или нет

Comment: *Куда мне прописать данные строки?* — очень сильно зависит, во-первых, от того, для чего нужна будет эта информация, а во-вторых, от того, каким образом у вас конфигурируется сеть. // в общем, одназночного кртакого ответа по приведённой вами информации дать просто невозможно. // мой добрый совет: не пользуйтесь той инструкцией, которую вы процитировали. без понимания происходящего у вас всё равно вряд ли получится «перевести» её на специфику вашего дистрибутива.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по содержимому - речь идёт о настройке статического ip. В debian\ubuntu это делается через файл `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Более подробно [тут](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D1%80%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E#%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8).